# The parameter is missing a value

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I am creating a report based in SSRS and I am getting an error related to the parameter missing a value.

I tried searching for a few links online but none of them have anything related to the issue I am facing.

The issue I am facing is that I have a few datasets with the query  defined inside the report itself. These queries are not producing the values as intended.

Below is relevant code that could be useful in understand the problem.

```
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>SBR_DATA</DataSourceName>
.
.
.
          <QueryParameter Name="@PU_CS">
            <Value>=Parameters!PU_CS.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
.
.
.
          <CommandText>
                SELECT XYZ FROM ABC
                WHERE Value in (@PU_CS)
          </CommandText>
</DataSet>
<DataSet Name="Pick_Up_List">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>SBR_DATA</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT
                    PQR AS PickUpList
                    FROM RST
        </CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="PickUpList">
          <DataField>PickUpList</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
</DataSet>
.
.
.
<ReportParameter Name="PU_CS">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <DataSetReference>
          <DataSetName>Pick_Up_List</DataSetName>
          <ValueField>PickUpList</ValueField>
        </DataSetReference>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>Pick Up City, State:</Prompt>
      <ValidValues>
        <DataSetReference>
          <DataSetName>Pick_Up_List</DataSetName>
          <ValueField>PickUpList</ValueField>
          <LabelField>PickUpList</LabelField>
        </DataSetReference>
      </ValidValues>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
</ReportParameter>
```

I expect that the result should be displayed as I am specifying each and every result and not missing anything.

Comment: This is really broad. When are you receiving this error? Saving? Report Execution?

Comment: Are you sure that your Pick_Up_List query is getting results for the parameter? You would get that error since the parameter doesn't Allow Null Values `<Nullable>true</Nullable>`.

Comment: @Pants I am getting this error at the time of Report Execution.

Comment: @HannoverFist Pick_Up_List query is getting results for the parameter. I ran that query as the subquery of the original query and It gave me the results.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you may need to check:

1. Do you put parameter @PU_CS at the first position in all parameters? Parameter with DB need to be placed as the first parameter to run the rerpot.
2. And try to set a default value for the parameter to see the result.

Comment: @ShelonZh

Can you share an example in the edit using my existing code?